# Encryption in Java using "AES/CFB/NoPadding" and decryption in Python using AES.MODE_CFB produce different results

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes

In Java, the code below can encrypt strings of any length and decrypt without any problem.

**Java code:**

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class AesEncryption {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        AesEncryption ae = new AesEncryption();
        byte[] secret = ae.encrypt("Hello World!");
        for (byte b : secret)
            System.out.print(String.format("%d, ", b));
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print(String.format("%s\n", ae.decrypt(secret)));
    }

    private final IvParameterSpec iv;
    private final SecretKeySpec keySpec;

    public AesEncryption() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] key = "thisisasecretkey".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(key);
        this.iv = new IvParameterSpec(md.digest());
        this.keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String content) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.keySpec, this.iv);
        return cipher.doFinal(content.getBytes());
    }

    public String decrypt(byte[] secret) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.keySpec, this.iv);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(secret));
    }
}
```

**Python code:**

```
import array
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

class AesEncryption:
    def __init__(self):
        key = 'thisisasecretkey'.encode('UTF-8')
        md = hashlib.md5()
        md.update(key)
        iv = md.digest()
        self.__cryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)
    
    def encrypt(self, content):
        return self.__cryptor.encrypt(AesEncryption.r_pad(content.encode('UTF-8')))[:len(content.encode('UTF-8'))]
    
    def decrypt(self, secret):
        return self.__cryptor.decrypt(secret)
    
    @staticmethod
    def r_pad(payload):
        length = 16 - (len(payload) % 16)
        return payload + (chr(length) * length).encode('UTF-8')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    secretstr = array.array('b', [-108, 20, -91, -103, 13, 59, 94, -51, 17, -104, -30, -83]).tostring()
    ae = AesEncryption()
    print(ae.decrypt(secretstr).decode('UTF-8'))
```

However when I pass the secret byte array produced by the Java code to PyCrypto, the decryption fails. The Python code uses `AES.MODE_CFB` and `segment_size = 128` to match the AES mode in Java, but the length of the plain text won't meet the 16-byte-block requirement. Changing the `segment_size` never produces the same result either. So I figure `NoPadding` may be the problem. What is the algorithm used by `AES/CFB/NoPadding` mode in Java? And how is it different from the algorithm used in PyCrypto? Thanks.

**Edit:**
Thanks to [Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) and [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150978/robert). As a stream cipher, CFB mode with `segment_size=128` should work correctly. The problem is caused by the bug in an outdated version of PyCrypto. Use latest PyCryptodome instead.

Comment: CFB mode emulates a stream cipher hence the padding should be irrelevant for this mode. BTW: I hope you are aware the deriving the iv from the key is a very very bad idea (simplifies brut-forcing the key). Hopefully this is just for demonstration purposes to have a fixed iv.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the advice. If I understand you correctly, in PyCrypto if I use the CFB mode, the segment size shouldn't be a problem right? But when I tried to run the Python code it threw an exception which indicates the length of input secret byte array must be a multiple of 16 bytes, that confuses me. And yes it is only for the demonstration to have a fixed IV, so don't worry about it.

Comment: segementsize is nothing standardized. The PyCrypto help says: `segment_size (integer) - (Only MODE_CFB).The number of bits the plaintext and ciphertext are segmented in. It must be a multiple of 8. If 0 or not specified, it will be assumed to be 8 bits.`

Comment: There are 2 (possibly copy/paste) bugs in the posted Python code (replace `Class` by `class` and the type code `'B'` by `'b'`). Then the ciphertext will be decrypted correctly using _PyCryptodome_. I.e. CFB in Java corresponds to `segment_size=128` in Python. No padding is necessary either, since CFB is a stream cipher mode. When using the outdated _PyCrypto_, however, the following error is displayed due to a _PyCrypto_ bug: _Input strings must be a multiple of the segment size 16 in length_, i.e. the bug requires padding. [Here](https://repl.it/languages/python3) you can try out both libs.

Comment: @Topaco Much appreciated! The problem was caused by an outdated version indeed. Also, thanks for pointing out the typos.